# Не считает и выводит 0

Tags: c#

Честно говоря эта проблема меня застигла врасплох

```
inversum = 7;
quantrow = 8;
secindex = 7;

double kendelkoef = 0;
double vvval  = (4 * inversum) / (quantrow * secindex);
kendelkoef = 1 - vvval;
textBox4.Text = kendelkoef.ToString();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И компилятор видит 0.0 вместо 0.5 (смотрим картинку)
была попытка написать так `vvval=Convert.ToDouble(выражние1/выражение2);`но всё-также при отладке он видит только 0.0 а не 0.5.

Решил чисто этот момент в консоли прорешать и результат такой же(показывает 0)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`String.Format` тоже не помог.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Целочисленная арифметика.

```
double inversum = 7;
quantrow = 8;
secindex = 7;
```

или

```
double vvval  = (4.0 * inversum) / (quantrow * secindex);
```

Answer (score 8):

Все правильно. 28/56 = 0, потому что целочисленное деление так работает. А потом этот ноль можно сколько угодно преобразовывать в double - он так нулем и останется.

Вот 28.0/56.0 будет уже 0.5. Преобразуйте в double операнды, а не результат.